# Set a variable equal to the output of a command containing non-command words

Tags: bash, arguments

I'm writing a small script in which I want to set the value of a variable equal to the output of a command. However, the command in question is a call to another script with command-line arguments. I'm using backticks as you normally should in this scenario, but the problem is that the the computer gives an error, in which it tries to interpret the command-line arguments as commands.

```
#!/bin/bash

filename="$1"

while read p; do
        echo "This is the gene we are looking at: ""$p"
        lookIn= `./findGeneIn "$p" burgdorferi afzelii garinii hermsii miyamotoi parkeri`
        echo "$lookIn"
        #grep "$p" "$lookIn""/""prokka_""$lookIn""/*.tsv" | awk '{print $1}' 
done < $filename
```

I'm trying to set variable `lookIn` equal to the output of `./findGeneIn "$p" burgdorferi afzelii garinii hermsii miyamotoi parkeri`, where `./findGeneIn` is a script, and the words burgdorferi,...,parkeri are command line arguments for `./findGeneIn`.

The issue, is that I get an error saying "burgdorferi: command not found". So it's trying to interpret those arguments as commands. How do I get it to not do that?

Comment: Remove the space after `lookIn=`. Also, use `$( )` instead of backticks, and quote the filename (`done < "$filename"`). [shellcheck.net](https://www.shellcheck.net) is good at spotting common mistakes like these.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
lookIn= `./findGeneIn "$p" burgdorferi afzelii garinii hermsii miyamotoi parkeri`
       ^
```

Delete the extra space. Assignments must not have spaces around the equal sign.

With the space there, Bash parses the line as `var=value command`, which runs a command with `$var` temporarily set to `"value"`. Or in this case, it interprets result of the backticks as a command name and `lookIn=` as an empty variable assignment.